# Graphics memory decreased after adding RAM

Tags: graphics-card

I have HP Pavilion G6 2004tx

Configuration:

**OS**: Windows 7 HB x64.
**CPU**: i5 2nd Gen.
**RAM**: 8GB DDR3 (4 + 4 newly added )
**GPU**: 2GB DDR3 - AMD Radeon HD 7670M
**HDD**: 500Gb

After adding **4 GB Transcend (1333 MHz)** RAM in laptop, I can see only 1780mb graphics memory available, Previously it was showing more than 3000mb.

Why this is happening? What should I do to get graphics memory back?

Answer (score 1):

The i5 has a built in GPU.  You were most likely looking at that as the graphics card and it was using the motherboard's ram for memory.

Now you are most likely seeing the Radeon's memory as it is 2GB.  This is the graphics card you want to use, not the GPU built into the CPU.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply,

But what should I do to get back graphics card memory?

Comment: you never lost any memory!  reread the answer.

Comment: Note that your Radeon has a feature (GART = Graphics Address Remapping Table) which allows it to use part of the 8GB DDR3 when its own 2GB is not sufficient.

Comment: Yes, but I want to know that how do I use graphics card as dedicated, and not shared with RAM?

Comment: when using the nvidia graphics card it uses its own memory, not RAM